# perl remove " in string and return a word from json

Tags: regex, json, perl

I have this string:
 `'{"file_type":"/video/2012/09/10/prn-exceo.jpg"}'`
 I want to have :
`'{file_type:/video/2012/09/10/prn-exceo.jpg}'`
  Tried :
`$str=~m/\"(.+)\"/`  and `$str=~ s/"//g;`
What i am doing wrong?

UPDATE
a json call gives me this string:
`'{"file_type":"/video/2012/09/10/prn-exceo.jpg"}'`
i am trying to return `prn-exceo.jpg` like this:
`my $json = JSON->new->allow_nonref->encode('prn-exceo.jpg');`

but i have a `parsererror`

Comment: Is this JSON? Might a JSON parser be more suited to whatever your underlying need?

Comment: you r right it is jason. Now i have a *parsererror* since i am trying to return 'prn-exceo.jpg` like this `my $json = JSON->new->allow_nonref->encode('prn-exceo.jpg');`. any help apreciated

Comment: I think you are using it incorrectly, perhaps edit your question to ask the question of what you are doing and how you are doing it. This is a classic XY problem. You are asking for help with X when your problem is actually Y. Please tell us the Y :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't doing anything wrong. The substitution does what you want.

```
david@elgin ~ $ cat x.pl
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.14;

my $str = '{"file_type":"/video/2012/09/10/prn-exceo.jpg"}';
$str=~ s/"//g;
say $str;
~ :
david@elgin ~ $ perl x.pl
{file_type:/video/2012/09/10/prn-exceo.jpg}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use the `tr` operator:

```
$str =~ tr/"//d;
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you are using JSON very incorrectly. Let me see if I understand you correctly, you are getting the string containing the JSON from some external source, then you want to get the value from the `file_type` key. In this case you want to decode the JSON string, not encode it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my $json_string = '{"file_type":"/video/2012/09/10/prn-exceo.jpg"}';

my $data = JSON->new->decode($json_string);
my $file = $data->{file_type};

print $file . "\n";

# if you just want the filename then use 

use File::Basename;

my $filename = fileparse $file;

print $filename . "\n";
```